# What is the reason that the world will end after 6/7 thousand years?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy

> Talmud, Tractate Sanhedrin [97a]: “Rav Kattina said: 'The world will exist for 6000 years and one (thousand) of destruction'

What is the hashkafic reason to only have a finite world? Wouldn't an infinitely good G-d want more souls to bestow good upon?

Comment: Note that this is the opinion of R. Katina, but is not the universal Jewish opinion. Rambam, for example, disagrees in Moreh Nevokhim (2:27-8).

Comment: Are you only confused about it not having an end but you are ok with it having a beginning?

Comment: @DoubleAA Why would there be confusion as to whether the world has a beginning?

Comment: @HaLailahHaZeh He's confused about why the world is finite based on the fact that it has an end. He could have been confused already based on it having a beginning, no?

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not particularly confused about the beginning in and of itself (i.e there are hashkafic reasons given for it's beginning, like the one I alluded to in my question, namely bestowing good upon the creation).

Comment: Yevamos 62a says there are a limited amount of souls in 'Guf' which until used up, Moshiach cannot come.

Comment: Also the gemara you quote likens this phase of 6-7 thousand as compared to shabbos. For whatever reason He created for 6 and rested on 7 He made a world of function for 6000 and nonfunctional for the last thousand.

Comment: @user6591 right, why isn't that guf a little bigger (i.e why would a benevolent being not want to bestow more benevolence)?